# how to stop ArgumentParser showing duplicate choices for option aliases

Tags: python, parameter-passing, optional-parameters

When I try putting multiple options (i.e '--loglevel', '--verbosity' and '-v') on a choice argument in ArgumentParser like this.

```
from argparse import ArgumentParser
_LOGLEVELS = ('CRITIAL','ERROR','WARNING','WARN','INFO','DEBUG')
parser = ArgumentParser(description='Logger Demo.')
parser.add_argument('--loglevel', '--verbosity', '-v', choices=_LOGLEVELS,  default='INFO', help='set the log level')
parser.parse_args()
```

and then give the --help option, the help duplicates choices for each option like this

```
optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --loglevel {CRITIAL,ERROR,WARNING,WARN,INFO,DEBUG}, --verbosity {CRITIAL,ERROR,WARNING,WARN,INFO,DEBUG}, -v {CRITIAL,ERROR,WARNING,WARN,INFO,DEBUG}
                        set the log level
```

.. which dosn't read well. Is there a way make the 3 aliased options --verbosity --loglevel and -v show the same choices like this so it is easier to read?

```
--loglevel --verbosity -v {CRITIAL,ERROR,WARNING,WARN,INFO,DEBUG}   set the log level.
```